# Artifactory Restrict upload to repository, allow copy from another repo

Tags: artifactory

How do I restrict users from manually deploying anything into a repository, at the same time allow them to copy from an another repository.

```
RepoA/Dir/File.txt  
RepoB/Dir
```

I would like to allow the copy of File.txt from RepoA to RepoB, this requires Deploy permissions to the RepoB. However, I would also like to restrict the manual deploy to RepoB. Anything coming into RepoB should be only from RepoA.

I tried this with the User Plugin with beforeCreate module, this restricts the Manual upload, however, this restricts the Copy function as well.

```
storage{ 
  beforeCreate { item ->
    log.debug("ENTER storage -> beforeCreate")
    if (item.getRepoKey().equals("RepoB")) {
    throw new CancelException("Artifact create not permitted", 403)
    }
    log.debug("EXIT storage -> beforeCreate")
}  }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to allow copy, just add a check that verifies that the same path (artifact) exists in `RepoA`. If it does - allow:

```
storage { 
  beforeCreate { item ->
        log.debug("ENTER storage -> beforeCreate")
        if (item.getRepoKey().equals("RepoB") &&
            !repositories.exist(RepoPathFactory.create('RepoA', item.repoPath)) {
            throw new CancelException("Artifact create not permitted", 403)
        }
        log.debug("EXIT storage -> beforeCreate")
    }  
}
```

Comment: Thanks JBaruch, The concept worked out really well. I had to change the syntax a bit for it to work. 

`String itemPath = item.repoPath.path`
`!repositories.exists(RepoPathFactory.create('RepoA', itemPath))`

Comment: I think I am wrong, with the syntax in the above comment, if I try to upload a file with the same name which exists in RepoA, it creates the file in RepoB